# Ubuntu 16.04 black screen after a while - Windows works perfect

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-8, screen

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 8.1 (dual boot).
Windows works perfectly.
Ubuntu works okay a while (sometimes the whole day, sometimes only 1 hour) and then comes a black screen, so that I have to restart my computer.

I can find only answers on 'black screen after boot' but that is not my problem.

Any solutions?

**Display Devices:**

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display  
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216 [GeForce GT 220] (rev a2)
Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. GT216 [GeForce GT 220]
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

**Manufacturer/model info:**

```
$ sudo lshw | grep product >file 
product: MS-7529 (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)  
product: G31M3-L V2(MS-7529)  
product: Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5300  @ 2.60GHz  
product: PartNum0  
product: PartNum1  
product: 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller  
product: 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Root Port  
product: GT216 [GeForce GT 220]  
product: GT216 HDMI Audio Controller  
product: NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller  
product: NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 1  
product: NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2  
product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller  
product: NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1  
product: UHCI Host Controller  
product: NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2  
product: UHCI Host Controller  
product: NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3  
product: UHCI Host Controller  
product: NM10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4  
product: UHCI Host Controller  
product: NM10/ICH7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller  
product: EHCI Host Controller  
product: 11n Adapter  
product: 82801 PCI Bridge  
product: 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge  
product: 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller  
product: NM10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode]  
product: NM10/ICH7 Family SMBus Controller  
product: Hitachi HDT72105  
product: DVD RW AD-7240S
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: also please edit with your this computer's manufacturer and model. The more info the better to solve something like this.

Comment: Edited. I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Nvidia drivers. Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install nvidia-340
```

Then reboot and disable Secure Boot in the BIOS if it is UEFI.

Comment: I tested it for a few days and it works great now. Thanks a lot!